# How to retrieve my data from database into checkbox list view type?

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve my data from database into checkbox list view, but I'm unable to do so. Below is the code that I'm already using to retrieve data from database into list view. But what I want is to retrieve into checkbox list view type so that I can check it. How can I do that?

public class StudentDetailActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

```
private ListView uGraduateNamesListView;
private Button addNewUndergraduateButton;


private ListAdapter uGraduateListAdapter;

private ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo> pojoArrayList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail);


    uGraduateNamesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.uGraduateListView);
    uGraduateNamesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    addNewUndergraduateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.namesListViewAddButton);
    addNewUndergraduateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();


    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

    uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent addNewUndergraduateIntent = new Intent(this, AddNewUndergraduateActivity.class);
    startActivity(addNewUndergraduateIntent);
}


public List<String> populateList(){

    List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String ugName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME));
        String ugUniId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_UNI_ID));
        double ugGpa = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_GPA));

        UndergraduateDetailsPojo ugPojoClass = new UndergraduateDetailsPojo();
        ugPojoClass.setuGraduateName(ugName);
        ugPojoClass.setuGraduateUniId(ugUniId);
        ugPojoClass.setuGraduateGpa(ugGpa);

        pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

        uGraduateNamesList.add(ugName);
    }

    sqliteDatabase.close();

    return uGraduateNamesList;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();
    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());        
    uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);        
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();
    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());        
    uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);    
}

public void onClick1 (View view)
{
Intent newIntent;
newIntent=new Intent(this,HomePageActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteUgraduateIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateDeleteUndergraduateActivity.class);

    UndergraduateDetailsPojo clickedObject =  pojoArrayList.get(arg2);

    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickedUgraduateName", clickedObject.getuGraduateName());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedUgraduateUniId", clickedObject.getuGraduateUniId());
    dataBundle.putDouble("clickedUgraduateGpa", clickedObject.getuGraduateGpa());

    updateDeleteUgraduateIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);

    startActivity(updateDeleteUgraduateIntent);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListActivity Provided in Android.
You only have to manage your data to required format for this ListActivity.

You Can place action on button instead of Menu Option.

```
 package your_package_name;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.content.ComponentName;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;



public class your_activity_name extends ListActivity {

private static final int checkedItem= 0;

private String[] databaseContent;

String checkedItems = new String(); // comma separated
String uncheckedItems = new String(); // comma separated

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    databaseContent = your_data_from_database // this array should contain your data from database.     
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, databaseContent));           

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); 


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);       

    menu.add(0, checkedItem, 0, R.string."String you want to show");                

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
{       

    switch(item.getItemId()) 
    {     
        case checked:
        {
            int reqlength = getListAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < reqlength ; i++) 
            {
                if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                    checkedItems = checkedItems.concat(databaseContent[i]).concat(",");
                }
                else {
                    uncheckedItems = uncheckedItems.concat(databaseContent[i]).concat(",");                     
                }                   
            } 
            Thread thread = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if ( checkedItems.length() > 0 || 
                         uncheckedItems.length() > 0 
                        ) 
                    {
                        //Here is your desired output in checkedItems & uncheckedItems

                    }                                           
                }
            };
            thread.start();

            Toast.makeText(your_activity_name.this, R.string.your_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            finish();               
            return true;
        }           

    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);       
}

@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
            super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
        }

}
```

For other way please see Link 
[Android ListView With Checkbox choice without using Built-in AistActivity](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Hope this will resolve your problem.